# Delete a reload a particular file into Chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, single-page-application

I am working on a single page application that loads several files (both JavaScript and HTML) in the first load.

What I need is a mechanism by which I can change a single JavaScript file and reload just that file.

Disabling the caching from developer tools will always load the entire files where as I need to reload just a single file (the one which I change) and load the rest of the files from the cache.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How this is done depends on how you are loading the scripts, where you are loading them from, and into what you are loading them. We need more information. A *manifest.json* would help. Showing us *exactly* how you are loading the scripts. Where the script is changed, etc.

Comment: What I was thinking was, Is there any way to delete a particular file from cache. If we can do that then browser should reload that the next time we try to access it.

Comment: The answer is normally no, but that does not mean you can not get a fresh copy. Rather than the inefficient method of your just asking for ideas, how about you provide more context so we narrow down what the possibilities are.